# Linq count returns 0 but foeach returns something else

Tags: c#, arrays, entity-framework, linq

Im currently programming a webinterface for gameservers in C# with Entity Framework and ASP-Net

and got following problem.

so this

```
string apikey = blablabla
userManager.Users.Count(u=> u.ApiKeys.Contains(apiKey) || u.SupportApiKey == apiKey))
```

should return 1 but returns 0

and this

```
bool found = false;
foreach (WebinterfaceUser u in userManager.Users)
    if (u.ApiKeys.Contains(apiKey) || u.SupportApiKey == apiKey)
        found = true;
```

return true (so essentially 1 because i have only one database entry)

so why is that?

it does not make sense to me because both functions should return the same result right?

im also kinda new to c# and maybe im missing something i hope you can help me :)

Comment: In the first version the filtering and counting is done by the database, in the second version it's done client side in c#. So my first guess is something like collation: the db might be comparing the strings case insensitive while c# works case sensitive. What does your row look like?

Comment: What variable are you setting in the first example that you get a value of 0?  don't you need an equal sign : int results = userManager........

Comment: Could be an implementation difference: Count is working with `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<User>` whereas foreach is working with `System.Collections.IEnumerator.GetEnumerator()`. They aren't the same thing though they probably should be backed by the same code.

Comment: The thing is that the comparison of SupportApiKey works!
its like the apikey list is not filled when working with linq

Comment: @AlwaysLearning because the question is about EF, I'm sure `Count()` here works on `IQueryable<User>`, not on `IEnumerable<User>`. So the first `Count` query is translated to SQL like `COUNT()...WHERE` and executed on the db. The `foreach` iterates over all users returned from the database and does the string comparisions client side.

Comment: @Justin99b added an answer if memory is not an issue

Comment: Can you please put up the exact complete code for what does and does not work, along with the class definition for this "User" entity? Also, can you post the method signature for the userManager.Users method. What Database are you connecting to? @Rene DB Case insensitivity would explain why the first example would work while the 2nd might not as C# will be case-sensitive with it's in-memory comparisons while the DB may, or may not be depending on collation. In this case C# works, but DB possibly doesn't.

Comment: @StevePy how i said its like the array isnt filled. my guess is that its...not kinda gets the db entry but rather the unfilled poco object or something like that. but that wouln't make any sense tho because the supportKey GUID has a correct value but the apikey array seems to be empty somehow via Linq

Comment: Ok, but we need to see the full picture. What is the definition for the WebInterfaceUsers class and the return type of this userManager.Users? You can verify if the DB is being hit by running a profilter. For SQL Server I use ExpressProfiler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is as following

```
new WebinterfaceDbContext().Users.ToList().First(u => u.ApiKeys.Contains(apiKey));
```

after some investigation and testing i got this error:

```
'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1[System.Guid]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.L inq.IQueryable`1[System.Guid]'
```

so i simply added ToList() to Users and it worked :)

Answer (score 1):

if memory is not an issue. try this.

```
var apiCounts = userManager.Users.ToList().Count(u=> u.ApiKeys.Contains(apiKey) || u.SupportApiKey == apiKey));
```

it will be executed on memory not on db, maybe something in db level vs server side is causing the error.

Comment: isnt that the same thing  as the second code i've posted? i mean... how much memory does it use? and do i need to dispose it manually ? i dont realy know that kind of stuff ^^

Comment: @Justin99b memory issue? it depends on the number of users, if it is in the million users. Executing it on memory would take a hit because you are loading all of the users without a filter. i also believe your code, if you have `sql profiler` will call all db users every iteration. try checking it